# Trouble using Java 2D Graphics: Cant Draw a Rectangle?

Tags: java

I am attempting to make a "Pong" game, and I am struggling to draw the Rectangle that will be the "Racket". I have attempted to use Java2D graphics, but it just doesn't want to work for me. The 2 links below will show the "Racket" class and "Window" class. The Racket class is where I draw the Racket for the game, and the Window class is where I make the JFrame. [Racket Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkOQm.png) [Window Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNDUJ.png)

Comment: Pleast post the code in your question with [edit] , rather than links to images of your code.

Comment: Welcome at the community. We like to help you, but to make it easy for everybody take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Even though you got some answers do the community this favour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supersimple. How could your `Window` class know that it should draw your 
`Racket`?

I tell you what todo but I won't provide code, because you only posted an image.

1. Extend `JFrame` instead of just instantiating it (or `JPanel` for reusage purposes)
2. Override the `paint` method (don't forget the `super.paint(g)` call)
3. Create an instance of Racket as a member of `Window` class
4. Call `racketInstance.paint(g)`

These are the simplest steps to follow if you want it to be drawn. But for your whole target this is not the best approach.

Comment: This is basically the same answer as Chuidang's. Just a bit more detailed.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!

Comment: Happy to help you. But a little bit googling may have helped you, no insult.

Answer (score 0):

You must extend JPanel and override the method paint(Graphics g). In this method, you must draw the Racket.
In your class Window, add your JPanel subclass instead of a standard javax.swing.JPanel.